# Python: Rows to Column Conversion in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Need help in converting rows answers to columns in python.Given below is sample dataset.
Thanks for Help..

```
ID| date         |question_id |Choice_id| answer
1 | 2020-01-01   | 471362125  |NAN      | 29720950
2 | 2020-01-01   | 471362121  |311470023| 8
3 | 2020-01-01   | 471362120  |311470024| 9
4 | 2020-01-01   | 471362524  |312472025| 5
5 | 2020-01-01   | 471362122  |NAN.     | Delivery Issue
```

Expected output

```
id|date|471362125_nan|471362121_311470023|471362120_311470024|471362524_312472025|471362122_NAN
1 | 2020-01-01| 29720950|8|9|5|Delivery Issue
```

I will rename this with question text using rename in pandas

Comment: Why is time `2020-01-01` part of column?..Also Please add more clarity as to what you want to convert as columns..The output is not clear

Comment: @LazyCoder: want to convert combination of (question_id,choice_id values) in to columns & use anwer as its value

Comment: @LazyCoder: 2020-01-01 is value of date column

Comment: I'm curious to know why do you wanna convert row to column? It just makes your life difficult. You can achieve same using `.map(question_rename_dict)` on question_id column after contact with choice ID columns.

Comment: @pythonlearner did my answer solve help you? If so, can you accept as solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the brute force technique using a lot of `iloc`, setting the column names appending and resetting the index. The main idea is that the column names and first row mainly come from two columns, so you append those together horizontally:

input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'date': {0: '2020-01-01',
  1: '2020-01-01',
  2: '2020-01-01',
  3: '2020-01-01',
  4: '2020-01-01'},
 'question_id': {0: 471362125,
  1: 471362121,
  2: 471362120,
  3: 471362524,
  4: 471362122},
 'Choice_id': {0: 'NAN',
  1: '311470023',
  2: '311470024',
  3: '312472025',
  4: 'NAN.'},
 'answer': {0: '29720950', 1: '8', 2: '9', 3: '5', 4: 'Delivery Issue'}})
```

code:

```
df1 = df.copy()
d = df1['date'].min()
i = df1['ID'].min()
df1.columns = df1['question_id'].astype(str) + '_' + df1['Choice_id'].astype(str).to_list()
b = df1.columns.to_list()
a = pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:,4]).T
a.columns = b
df2 = a.append(df1).iloc[0:1]
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename({'index' : 'date'}, axis=1).reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename({'index' : 'id'}, axis=1)
df2['date'] = d
df2['id'] = i
df2.columns.names=['']
df2
```

output:

```
    id  date        471362125_NAN   471362121_311470023 471362120_311470024 471362524_312472025 471362122_NAN.
0   1   2020-01-01  29720950        8                   9                   5   Delivery Issue
```